# Show that the equation $6x^4-7x+1=0$ has at most 2 real roots.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the equation $6x^4-7x+1=0$ has at most 2 real roots.

I tried the calculus method with Euler's identity - but I am afraid that means I cam completely missing something in terms of Real Analysis

Comment: You can see that 1 is one root than try to divide equation with $(x-1)$

Comment: When I divide by x-1, how can I show that that 3rd degree polynomial has at most one real root?

Answer (score 6):

The derivative of the function is $24x^3-7$, which has only one real solution, at $x = \sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{24}}$.  Since the function is only horizontal at that one value of $x$, it cannot have more than two real roots (since between any two distinct zeros, the function must be horizontal at least once—it's a polynomial).

Comment: The other root is approximately $0.14322$, according to WolframAlpha, and the horizontal point noted in my answer is indeed between that and $1$, at about $0.66318$.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing that 1 is a solution we can divide $6x^4-7x+1$ with $x-1$ to get 
$6x^3+6x-1=0$ and using Vietta's formulas we get 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=0$$
$$x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1=1$$
$$x_1x_2x_3=-\frac{1}{6}$$
From first two equation we find that $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=-2$ so at least one of them is not real and from that combining with third knowing that product of not real with real(except 0) gives a not real number we get that at least two of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are not real.
So the result follows.

Comment: $(x-1)(6x^3+6x-1)=6x^4-6x^3+6x^2-7x+1$